# Former and latter for groups

Tags: word-usage

If I am comparing multiple things and grouping them, can I use former and latter?

Basic idea:

> A, B, and C performed well, D and E did not. The difference is former has *certain trait* and the latter has *another trait*.

Answer (score 2):

As your example stands, it's not immediately clear (although most people could deduce it) that *former* applies to A, B & C.

You can improve it by explicitly stating that it's a group, e.g.

> A, B, and C performed well, D and E did not. The difference is that the former group has a *certain trait* and the latter has *another trait*.

Comment: Or "The difference is that the former group has a different trait than the latter"?